# Desktop not powering ON

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, desktop-computer

I have a weird issue of our desktops supplied to customers. At customers site they are not turning on but when I bring it my office it is working fine. It tries to start at customer site, fan starts and in few seconds it stops. Waited for 24 hours for as cooling down period but no luck. Brought to office and worked fine. Tried turning on with different plugs and cable at customer location but no luck. Also it is not happening with one customer location. Any key points to check which I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: It might be smps issue check the power wattage/Voltages at your shop and client locations and if possible try changing the SMPS.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any details on which power source your office and your customers are using, but make sure the 110 V/220 V switch is set correctly (if the power supply on that machine has one, as some newer ones do not); it's typically a flat, inset, red switch located at the top of the power supply, near the AC power connector and switch.

You'd usually see other indicators if this were the problem, but still worth double checking, since stranger things have happened.

I should also note that if it's already set correctly, you shouldn't mess with it; you could risk damaging components.

Answer (score 0):

Well from the fact that the power supply works fine in your office, that means the voltage switch is set okay.

well my advice would be to try a different working power supply and check results, failing that...there is definately a problem with the power in your customers side, then you may adjust the voltage switch but as been said on the previous answer, its risky.